# How to make items flip right and left while scrolling horizontally with List.builder in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, listview

I'd like to get the result of **image 1**, but I am stuck at **image 2**. I want to flip the card to right and left while scrolling as shown in image 1.
Here is my code,

```
Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: biography.length,
              itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    // interstitialAd?.show();
                    _showBottomSheet(context, index);
                  },
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                    child: HeroCard(
                      biography: biography[index],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
```

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]